# N choose k for large n and k

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, combinations

I have n elements stored in an array and a number k of possible subset over n(n chose k).
I have to find all the possible combinations of k elements in the array of length n and, for each set(of length k), make some calculations on the elements choosen.

I have written a recursive algorithm(in C++) that works fine, but for large number it crashes going out of heap space.

How can I fix the problem? How can I calculate all the sets of n chose k for large n and k? 
Is there any library for C++ that can help me?

I know it is a np problem but I would write the best code in order to calculate the biggest numbers possible.

Which is approximately the biggest numbers (n and k)beyond which it becames unfeasible?

I am only asking for the best algorithm, not for unfeasible space/work.

Here my code

```
vector<int> people;
vector<int> combination;

void pretty_print(const vector<int>& v) 
{
    static int count = 0;
    cout << "combination no " << (++count) << ": [ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { cout << v[i] << " "; }
        cout << "] " << endl;
}

void go(int offset, int k) 
{
    if (k == 0) {
        pretty_print(combination);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = offset; i <= people.size() - k; ++i) {
        combination.push_back(people[i]);
        go(i+1, k-1);
        combination.pop_back();
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = #, k = #;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { people.push_back(i+1); }
        go(0, k);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what you mean by "n chose k"? please specify more clearly what combination you have to count

Comment: Check out http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/generating-combinations-1/

Comment: You might want to use properties of the pascal triangle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle

Comment: isn't the combination just what OP needs?

Comment: @computer All the subset of k elements in a set of n elements. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: @IlyaBursov Thanks, but for large numbers it crashes

Comment: @harpun Dinamic programming won't help me, I need all the subsets, not numbers.

Comment: @Nadir what numbers you need? did you calculate final count already?

Comment: @IlyaBursov For example n=100, k=10, for my task I need numbers even bigger than these

Comment: @Nadir it is 17,310,309,456,440 combinations, do you have enough memory for this?

Comment: There is a combinations thing in [here](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/blob/master/combinations.hpp)

Comment: @IlyaBursov I do not need to store all the sets, I have to make some computation on the elements of the set, in my algorithm I will not have a lot of big numbers, but if I have, I don't want to have my algorithm to crash. It crashes for smaller number than 100 and 10.

Comment: please post your algorithm

Comment: @Nadir the thing I posted won't crash but it will also never finish the amount of calculations you are asking for couldn't be done by a supercomputer

Comment: @Nadir A dynamic programming solution exist which can calculate nCk such that nck<10^18. Tell me if you need some explanation regarding this!

Comment: @Nadir Your text talks about *n choose k*, but your code does not. This is confusing. It's not clear (1) how often you need to compute *n choose k* (and if you want to compute it for different *k* but the same *n* etc) and (2) what you mean with *large* (10,1000,10^6,10^12). The best method critically depends on the answers to these two questions.

Comment: @Walter In my algorithm ideally n and k can reach values of order order of 10^3 each one. I know it is not feasible with this value, but I want an algorithm to reach the higher values! 
My algorithm gives exactly n chose k. Try!

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja is the solution calculationg only the number of solutions or providing them? If providing, I am interested on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is non recursive algorithm:

```
const int n = ###;
const int k = ###;

int currentCombination[k];
for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
    currentCombination[i]=i;
currentCombination[k-1] = k-1-1; // fill initial combination is real first combination -1 for last number, as we will increase it in loop

do
{
    if (currentCombination[k-1] == (n-1) ) // if last number is just before overwhelm
    {
        int i = k-1-1;
        while (currentCombination[i] == (n-k+i))
            i--;

        currentCombination[i]++;

        for (int j=(i+1); j<k; j++)
            currentCombination[j] = currentCombination[i]+j-i;
    }
    else
        currentCombination[k-1]++;

    for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
        _tprintf(_T("%d "), currentCombination[i]);
    _tprintf(_T("\n"));

} while (! ((currentCombination[0] == (n-1-k+1)) && (currentCombination[k-1] == (n-1))) );
```

Comment: Your algorithm work, but: (10 5) end correctly in 1 second, (10 6)crashes

Comment: @Nadir than you copied it wrong, it works for any N/K, K is up to 2^30 (on 32bit) and 2^62 (on 64bit)

Comment: Yes, I wrote wrong, I mean (100 6) not (10 6). In my pc (100 6) does not work, does it work in yours?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works, it was a Netbeans problem! Really thank you!

Comment: int currentCombination[k]; VLA not allowed in C++

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive algorithm might be blowing the stack.  If you make it non-recursive, then that would help, but it probably won't solve the problem if your case is really 100 choose 10.  You have two problems.  Few, if any, computers in the world have 17+ terabytes of memory.  Going through 17 trillion+ iterations to generate all the combinations will take way too long.  You need to rethink the problem and either come up with an N choose K case that is more reasonable, or process only a certain subset of the combinations.

You probably do not want to be processing more than a billion or two combinations at the most - and even that will take some time.  That translates to around 41 choose 10 to about 44 choose 10.  Reducing either N or K will help.  Try editing your question and posting the problem you are trying to solve and why you think you need to go through all of the combinations.  There may be a way to solve it without going through all of the combinations.

If it turns out you do need to go through all those combinations, then maybe you should look into using a search technique like a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) or [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).  Both of these hill climbing search techniques provide the ability to search a large space in a relatively small time for a close to optimal solution, but neither guarantee to find the optimal solution.

Comment: I have a difficult algorithm that uses boolean data of a row of a matrix as the array and finds subsets at increasing value of k of the positions that takes value 1. In normal conditions the 1 in the row are few but I cannot rely on this.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, it's not clear what you really want.

1. If you want to compute (*n choose k*) for relatively small values, say *n,k* < 100 or so, you may want to use a recursive method, using Pascals triangle.
2. If *n,k* are large (say *n=1000000, k=500000*), you may be happy with an approxiate result using Sterlings formula for the factorial: (*n choose k*) = `exp(loggamma(n)-loggamma(k)-loggamma(n-k))`, computing `loggamma(x)` via Sterling's formula.
3. If you want (*n choose k*) for all or many *k* but the same *n*, you can simply iterate over *k* and use (*n choose k+1*) = ((*n choose k*)*(*n-k*))/(*k+1*).

Comment: Really sorry but:
"I have to find all the possible combinations of k elements in the array of length n and, for each set(of length k), make some calculations on the elements choosen."
To me it seams enough clear. I need all the subset of k elements in a set with n elements. I need all the sets, not the numers.
As you pointed in point 1: n,k < 100 use recursion. With n=100 and k=7 recursion does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next_permutation()` in `algorithm.h` to generate all possible combinations.

Here is some example code:

```
bool is_chosen(n, false);
fill(is_chosen.begin() + n - k, is_chosen.end(), true); 
do
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(is_chosen[i])
            cout << some_array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
} while( next_permutation(is_chosen.begin(), is_chosen.end()) );
```

Don't forget to include the algorithm.

Comment: next_permutation generates permutations.  N choose k is concerned with combinations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient